# Show $\exists v_{0} (\phi \rightarrow \forall v_{0} \phi)$ is valid.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Show that $\exists v_{0} (\phi \rightarrow \forall v_{0} \phi)$ is valid.

So what I have done is that I start with the assumption that it is not valid and trying to get a inconsistency.

> $s \not\in \text{Sat}_{M} (\exists v_{0} (\phi \rightarrow \forall
>  v_{0} \phi)) $
>
> $s \not\in \text{Sat}_{M} (\neg \forall v_{0} \neg(\phi \rightarrow
>  \forall v_{0} \phi))$
>
> $s \not\in {^NM} \setminus \text{Sat}_{M} (\forall v_{0} \neg(\phi
>  \rightarrow \forall v_{0} \phi))$
>
> $s \in \text{Sat}_{M} (\forall v_{0} \neg(\phi \rightarrow \forall
>  v_{0} \phi))$
>
> $s \in A_{0}(\text{Sat}_{M} (\neg(\phi \rightarrow \forall v_{0}
>  \phi)))$
>
> $s(a/0) \in \text{Sat}_{M} (\neg(\phi \rightarrow \forall v_{0}
>  \phi))$ for all $a\in M$
>
> $s(a/0) \in {^NM} \setminus \text{Sat}_{M} (\phi \rightarrow \forall
>  v_{0} \phi)$ for all $a\in M$
>
> $s(a/0) \not\in \text{Sat}_{M} (\phi \rightarrow \forall v_{0} \phi)$
>   for all $a\in M$
>
> $s(a/0) \not\in ({^NM} \setminus \text{Sat}_{M} (\phi)) \cup (\text{Sat}_{M}(\forall v_{0} \phi))$ for all $a\in M$
>
> From here I get two conditions (not sure if the right word).
>
> 1.
>
> $s(a/0) \in \text{Sat}_{M} (\phi)$ for all $a\in M$
>
> and
>
> 2.
>
> $s(a/0) \not\in \text{Sat}_{M}(\forall v_{0} \phi)$ for all $a\in M$
>
> $s(a/0) \not\in A_{0}(\text{Sat}_{M}(\phi))$ for all $a\in M$
>
> $s(a/0)s(b/0) \not\in \text{Sat}_{M}(\phi)$ for all $a\in M$ and for
>   some $b \in M$
>
> Now since we have that for all $a \in M$, $s(a/0) \in \text{Sat}_{M}
>  (\phi)$ and $s(a/0) \not\in \text{Sat}_{M} (\phi)$ we have a
>   inconsistency.

This is what I've done but I have a feeling in the back of my head that there is something wrong in my solution.

Comment: This is known as The Drinker's Paradox. There is someone in the bar, that if they take a sip, *everyone* is taking a sip.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is true. However while I can find lot of different kinds of proofs for this I was wondering if what I have done here is correct or not. Couldn't find similiar style solutions anywhere and that is why I am asking this.

Comment: Admittedly, I have no idea what half the symbols in your proof mean. So I can't really give my opinion on the topic.

Comment: Up to the "separation" of the argument in point 1. and 2. it looks fine to me... You are saying (correct me if I'm worng) that the variable assignment function $s(a/0)$ satisfy $\phi$ and does not satisfy $\forall v_0 \phi$, for all $a \in M$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that is correct.

Comment: At this point, I'm quite loosing me... To say that $s(a/0)$ does not satisfy $∀v_0 ϕ$, means that $s(b/0)$ does not satisfy $\phi$, for some $b \in M$. Thus, we have $s(b/0)$ does not sat $\phi$; but by 1. $s(b/0)$ does sat $\phi$ (because $s(a/0)$ does sat $\phi$, for every $a \in M$), and we have the contradiction.

Comment: Thus, in the end: it works, provided that the symbolism is correctly "unwinded".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Not if the bar is empty! =)

Comment: @user21820: The bar is never empty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You mean there is no bar if nobody is around to drink? =)

Comment: @user21820: No. :)